# Adding text before/after with multiple use of current text in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

What if I have this:

```
BTC/XRP
BTC/BCH
BTC/LTC
```

And I need to change it to this:

```
        {
            name: 'BTC/XRP',
            visible: false,
            data:data['BTC/XRP']?data['BTC/XRP']:[]
        },
        {
            name: 'BTC/BCH',
            visible: false,
            data:data['BTC/BCH']?data['BTC/BCH']:[]
        },
        {
            name: 'BTC/LTC',
            visible: false,
            data:data['BTC/LTC']?data['BTC/LTC']:[]
        }
```

I have a lot of these and editing it by hand would be a really long process.
I've tried some variations of regex but I can't find the logic of how would you do something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+$`
- Replace with: `{\n\tname: '$0',\n\tvisible: false,\n\tdata:data['$0']?data['$0']:[]\n},\n`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>